# Update jiffies value after waking up from suspend

Tags: linux-kernel

The global variable `jiffies` holds the number of ticks that have occurred since the system booted. On boot, the kernel initializes the variable to zero, and it is incremented by one during each timer interrupt.

But how the kernel updates this value after waking up from suspend?

How the kernel calculates the time that it had conducted in suspend mode?

Comment: AFAIK It doesn't as during the suspend the timer wasn't interrupted.

Comment: It seems to me I found answer: see `tick_do_update_jiffies64()` which defined in `tick-sched.c`